# Cookies section not properly working in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and I am using Nextjs. Right now I am working on the login module. After getting the correct credentials I am saving the user email in "cookie". Everything is working fine but I want to show the login page only to users that have not logged in.

In other words I want if user is already logged in and tries to open the login page,
to be redirect to the "dashboard" page. I tried with following code but its giving me the following error:

```
Error serializing .cookies returned from getServerSideProps Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value.
```

I tried with following server side code

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context: { req: { headers: { cookie: any; }; }; }) {
 const cookies = context.req.headers.cookie;
  if (cookies) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/dashboard",
      },
      props:{},
    };
  }
      
  return {
    props: {
      cookies,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You need to access it as `context.req.headers.cookies` instead of `cookie`. Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter

Comment: @SumitSurana can you please explain or write code so i can check and implement at my side

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly clear on why Next.js refuses to render the page: You are trying to return `undefined` for `.cookies` (presumably in `props` in your bottom most return) which is not serializable, since undefined values are omitted in JSON.stringify.

You can try this out by running `console.log(JSON.stringify({cookies: undefined}));` in your browser console for example, which will print an empty object.

*As to why `cookies` is undefined, that's something you'll have to figure out; it's quite likely that [Sumit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781093/cookies-section-not-properly-working-in-reactjs/74781201#comment131977444_74781093) is accurate!*

Now, conveniently, the error also tells you what to do. Either don't include the cookies property or ensure that it's null.

For the latter, you can do something like this:

```js
return {
  props: {
    cookies ?? null,
  },
};
```

This will ensure that an undefined value will be converted to null, a null value will stay null and an empty string will stay an empty string *(for more information on the nullish-coalescing operator, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing))*.

Now I'd argue that it's not even sensible to include the `cookies` property, since in this implementation it's always going to be falsy (i.e. an empty string, undefined or null) which probably won't help lots as a prop, since you already know the user is not logged in, so you can just return an empty props object.

---

Sidenote: When continuing, make sure that you are actually checking the cookie's value. Currently I can "log in" by creating a cookie myself as a user.

Comment: can you please update your answer so i can understand

Comment: I can sure try but you'd have to tell me what you don't understand first :)